# Analysis Services - TMSL - Execute from C#

Tags: service, refresh, analysis

I looking for a way to execute (what I think is called) TMSL against a Microsoft Analysis Services. I am trying to Process one single table, from a Dot.Net C# application. The JOSN I need to send to the Analysis Service looks something like this:

```
{  
  "refresh": {  
    "type": "full",  
    "objects": [  
      {  
        "database": "BaseName",  
        "table": "TableName"  
      }  
    ]  
  }  
}
```

how do I do? are there something like ado.net that can do the job?

Peter

Answer (score 0):

I found that this works:

```
            StringBuilder qry = new StringBuilder();

            qry.Clear();
            qry.AppendLine(" ");
            qry.AppendLine("{   ");
            qry.AppendLine("  \"refresh\": {   ");
            qry.AppendLine("    \"type\": \"full\",   ");
            qry.AppendLine("    \"objects\": [   ");

            bool AddTegn = false;
            foreach (string TableName in TableNames)
            {
                if (AddTegn)
                {
                    qry.AppendLine("      ,   ");
                }
                AddTegn = true;

                qry.AppendLine("      {   ");
                qry.AppendLine("        \"database\": \"" + DataBaseName + "\",   ");
                qry.AppendLine("        \"table\": \"" + TableName + "\"   ");
                qry.AppendLine("      }   ");
            }

            qry.AppendLine("    ]   ");
            qry.AppendLine("  }   ");
            qry.AppendLine("}   ");

            AdomdConnection con = "[Connection String]";
            con.Open();
            AdomdCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand(); //new AdomdCommand(qry.ToString(), con);
            cmd.CommandText = qry.ToString();

            cmd.CommandTimeout = 3600;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            try
            {
                int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (con != null)
                {
                    con.Close();
                }

                if (cmd != null)
                {
                    cmd.Dispose();
                }
                if (con != null)
                {
                    con.Dispose();
                }
            }
```